# Using Omit<T,k> or Pick<T,k> in Typescript (+ React), yet the field is still there

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### Issue

If I've got a `type Foo={'a':string,'b':string}`, when I use `Pick<Foo,'a'>` or `Omit<Foo,'b'>`, the field `b` is still present in the resulting object (see MWE below).

### Context

I want to downcast a Props type in Typescript + React, to keep only the data I want to display in a Material-UI Table component. More precisely, [MUI-Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables) which is built upon the Table component of Material-UI. I think it makes sense to keep only the data I need. It is also a necessity because of how the props of `MUIDatable` are set.

### MWE

In order to do so, I use `Pick<Foo,'a'>` Except the other fields are still present.

Here is a MWE.

```
    type Foo = {
        a: string
        b: string
    }

    type Bar = Pick<Foo, 'a'>

    const foo: Foo = { a: 'first', b: 'second' }
    const bar: Bar = foo as Bar
    console.log(bar)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#)

So my `bar = foo as Bar` or `<Bar>foo` is still equal to `{a: 'first', b:'second'}` while I expected only `a` to be picked.

I don't understand why. I am new to typescript, I used this as a resource to pick this solution:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk

### Questions

- Why doesn't this work ?
- **How can I remove or only keep certain fields in a typescript type ?**

Comment: Typescript provides static type checking and all the types are erased at compile time. `as Bar` is not casting - it is type assertion, it doesn't affect anything at runtime

Comment: Ah yes of course. So I must use a mapper to remove those fields

Comment: If you have Underscore or Lodash in your project, then you can use `_.pick(data, "a")` or `_.omit(data, "b")`. Both libraries provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Aleksey L. in the comments, the reason this doesn't work is that typescript typings are erased at compile time and don't affect anything at runtime.

They don't change the values, unlike cast at runtime in other languages.

Hence, I need to modify the value of `foo` to get the `bar` I want.